# Best way to execute sql insert statements in a loop from bash?

Tags: bash, sqlplus

I'm executing snmpget commands every 10 seconds in an infinite loop and I want to persist the snmpget responses in an Oracle database.

**script.sh**

```
    while true
        do
            resp=$(snmpget $snmpVersion $communityString $MiBList $IP $OID)
            sqlplus username/password@DB @query.sql $resp
            sleep 10
        done
```

**query.sql**

```
insert into table (column) values(&value);
exit;
```

The problem is I open and close connections every 10 seconds repeatedly. I think it's not effective. So how can I get a connection for once and use it without opening and closing connections everytime?

Comment: Set up a web service?

Comment: Thanks for your advice @PaulKienitz. However, I need to enhance the existing one.

Comment: Use a higher language (Perl, Python, Ruby) that provides convenient libraries.

Comment: Console yourself with the thought that web applications make and break their database connections hundreds of times a second.

Comment: If the records don't need to be inserted real time, a quick and simple change would be to dump the queries to a text file and then import them once an hour or so.

Comment: It's real-time @AlexHowansky.

Comment: Yeah ok, figured that was likely the case with SNMP but didn't know your use case. Oh well.

Comment: I would console myself if I wouldn't know how ineffective they're @PaulKienitz

Comment: Then console yourself with the thought that database engines are well optimized to handle cases where the same connection is periodically reused.

Comment: Do you *think* this is a bad idea for some real reason or do you *know* this is a bad idea? Have you profiled/timed/watched this to see if the usage is noticably higher than it would be some other way? (It probably is higher the question is just how much higher.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I had something with the sybase equivalent (isql) where it was "outside" the loop structure, connected by a pipe, ie `while true ; do resp=... ; echo "$resp" ;sleep 30 ; done | isql -u ....` . Maybe it required command grouping as well (with `{ resp=... ; }` ).Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, bash is not the best tool to use Oracle connection pooling. But if a connection is established in a few milliseconds it is not that bad to connect frequently. You could also write data to a file and upload it with another process not every 10 seconds, but maybe less frequently if that's an issue.